# linux bash inet_ntoa inet_aton

Tags: linux, debian, inet

I should be blind as I could not find these commands available in the ubuntu and debian's distribution, neither the package containing them.

Shall I code and compile them in C by myself (or write or find this code in perl or whatever language) or is it (I mean inet_aton, inet_ntoa ..) available as a bash command somewhere within these distros ?

Thx

Comment: I'm surprised you need them on a bash commandline. By all means, implement them (in perl seems sane to me)

Comment: just because I have some admin scripts written in bash and, for portability reasons, I would like to avoid invoking other interpreters just for a 1 line need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`inet_ntoa` and `inet_aton` aren't commands - they're library functions, for converting between textual and binary representations of IP addresses.

You can get at these functions easily using the `Socket` module in Perl:

```
$ perl -e 'use Socket; print inet_aton("123.45.67.89"), "\n"'
{-CY
$ perl -e 'use Socket; print inet_ntoa("{-CY"), "\n"'
123.45.67.89
```

or the `socket` module in Python:

```
$ python -c 'import socket; print socket.inet_aton("123.45.67.89")'
{-CY
$ python -c 'import socket; print socket.inet_ntoa("{-CY")'
123.45.67.89
```

but I'm not sure why you'd want to be working with the binary representation of an address in a bash script.  (The bytes of the address 123.45.67.89 in the examples above happen to correspond to printable ASCII characters, but you can't expect that to be true in general...)

Answer (score 0):

At the risk of self-promoting, pure-Bash implementations are available [at this Github repo](https://github.com/BMDan/inet_aton).